# Problema na codificação A\u015bvagho\u1e63a (Python3)?

Tags: json, python-3.x

Estou trabalhando com o wikipedia, e estou com alguns problemas codificação. Quando adiciono tal link no meu navegador dá tudo certo:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%C5%9Bvagho%E1%B9%A3a

Que vai para o artigo com o sequinte nome:

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aśvaghoṣa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%C5%9Bvagho%E1%B9%A3a)

Que é o mesmo artigo porém a url está sendo mostrada de forma diferente.
Ou seja há uma codificação ocorrendo aí.

Porém estou minerando os topviews do wikipedia:

https://tools.wmflabs.org/topviews/?project=en.wikipedia.org&platform=all-access&date=yesterday&excludes=

E no caso desse artigo eu recebi esse mesmo título com o sequinte nome atraves da API:

[https://tools.wmflabs.org/pageviews/api.php?project=en.wikipedia.org&start=2018-09-13&end=2018-09-13&pages=Aśvaghoṣa](https://tools.wmflabs.org/pageviews/api.php?project=en.wikipedia.org&start=2018-09-13&end=2018-09-13&pages=A%C5%9Bvagho%E1%B9%A3a)

```
"A\u015bvagho\u1e63a": {
  "assessment": "Stub",
  "num_users": 1,
  "assessment_img": "f/f5/Symbol_stub_class.svg",
  "num_edits": 1
},
```

Porém quando vou tentar montar a sequinte url:

`https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A\u015bvagho\u1e63a`

Concerteza não funciona.

O que eu quero saber como consigo codificar desta maneira (Em python3):

`A\u015bvagho\u1e63a  -> A%C5%9Bvagho%E1%B9%A3a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alguns módulos que podem realizar essa codificação:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""html encoding (Escaping HTML)"""
import cgi
import html
from urllib.parse import quote_plus

string = 'A\u015bvagho\u1e63a'

# cgi.escape(), utilize ele apenas com Python 2.
# No Python 3 ele irá entrar em desuso em versões futuras (Deprecated).
print('CGI escape:', cgi.escape(string))
print('HTML escape:', html.escape(string))
print('Quote plus:', quote_plus(string))

URL = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/'

print('CGI escape:', URL + cgi.escape(string))
print('HTML escape:', URL + html.escape(string))
print('Quote plus:', URL + quote_plus(string))
```

Acredito que existam outras formas, contudo isso irá depender de com você está buscando e salvando os dados.